# The best way to define character set of an HTML5 Web Page?

Tags: html

So what is the best way to define? Thanks!

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

or

```
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

or

```
  <meta http-equiv='charset' content='utf-8'>
```

Comment: The best way is probably to be sure to set the `Content-type` header when the page is requested from the server.

Comment: Your edit removed any context for some of the answers...

Answer (score 2):

The first option, `<meta charset='utf-8'>`, is preferred, primarily because it's shortest.

Note that the charset declaration should be the first child of the `<head>`, before any user-controlled content.  (in particular, before the `<title>`)

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent in HTML5, but I'd recommend using the first form, because it's shorter and easier to remember and was designed for backwards compatibility with older browsers, even in Internet Explorer 6 ([see](http://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute)).

Answer (score 1):

The best, and recommended, way is to specify the character encoding (“charset”) both in a `Content-Type` HTTP header and in a `meta` tag or, in the case of UTF-8, using a Byte Order Mark at the start. Note that any conflict between the HTTP header and a `meta` tag is resolved in favor of the HTTP header.

It is much less relevant which of the two forms of `meta` you use, but the shorter is safer (less opportunities for mistyping or copy error).

References: [Specifying the document's character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset) in HTML5 CR and W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

The third tag mentioned in the question, `<meta http-equiv='charset' content='utf-8'>`, is invalid and has no effect. (The W3C validator says: “Bad value charset for attribute http-equiv on element meta.”)

Answer (score -1):

the best way to define the Meta Charset follows:

`<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`

The TAG above is the more complete.

http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.pt-br.php